# How to add a border-less table in iText

Tags: java, itext

I want to add two strings to align both sides of the same row. For this task i am using a table. I want this table to be border-less. I tried out few examples but nothing worked.

Here's the current code :

```
    public void footer(Document document, String date) throws DocumentException {

    document.add(new Paragraph("footer"));
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(date);
    paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph("ABC Holdings (pvt) Ltd");


    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfPCell cellOne = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(paragraph));
    PdfPCell cellTwo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(paragraph2));
    table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(0);

    table.addCell(cellOne);
    table.addCell(cellTwo);

    document.add(table);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I resolved it. iText have provided the methods to manipulate the table.

```
    public void footer(Document document, String date) throws DocumentException {

    document.add(new Paragraph("footer"));
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(date);
    paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph("ABC Holdings (pvt) Ltd");


    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfPCell cellOne = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(paragraph));
    PdfPCell cellTwo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(paragraph2));

    cellOne.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    cellTwo.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    cellOne.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    cellTwo.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);

    table.addCell(cellOne);
    table.addCell(cellTwo);

    document.add(table);

}
```

Comment: Just FYI, the iText release you are using is nearing end of maintenance by the end of the year. It might be worth the effort (if you are still early in the project) to check out iText7.

Comment: Is that so. Thanks for the news.